# Не работают горячие клавиши в Visual Studio.

Tags: ide, visual-studio

Не работают горячие клавиши в Visual Studio. Установил Resharper, потом удалил его. 
Например, выделяю код "Ctrl+E, Ctrl+C" - говорит, что такой команды нет. Как исправить?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так: Resharper->Options->Environment->Keyboard & Menus там выберите нужную схему (ReSharper 2.x наверно), жмите Apply Scheme, Save и усё

Comment: Ой, 4 года почти вопросу, как-то он у меня вылез в топ((

Comment: Пользователь community мог поднять - он это делает раз в час. Кстати, у топикастера решарпен снесен, так что просто сброс шорткатов должен был помочь. Может быть он просто не ту схему выбрал.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сбросить настройки: [Reset All Your Shortcuts](https://web.archive.org/web/20151118042557/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/zainnab/archive/2010/08/05/keyboard-shortcuts-reset-all-your-shortcuts-vstiptool0064.aspx).

Comment: Не получилось!